# How to play sounds in thread from list in Qt 5.4

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, audio

I'm doing sound effects for application with Qt 5.4. 
Sounds effects are stored in List when user does something and I'm trying to play the List of sounds in thread.

I have tried to use QTimer for looping list and playing sound after few milliseconds. But this way it's starts hanging the application after the list has 4 items. This makes those effects really weird.

Now I'm trying to use a QThread in this way.

Run Method:

```
    while(true){ 
       if(queue.size() > 0){
          QString path = queue.front();
          QSound::play(path); 

       }
       this->sleep(500);
    }
```

But with doing like this it dosen't play sounds at all.
How I do implement sounds effects right in Qt application.

Comment: Your thread will need an event loop, so I suggest reading [this article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) on how to really, truly use QThread, rather than inheriting from it.

Comment: QSound::play() is not blocking (and you do not need a separate thread actually). You have to check isFinished() before playing the next one, but not in a loop but in a queued connection or timer handler.